# Why is my English "worlds better" than yours but never "the best by worlds"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, colloquialisms, comparatives

In speech when making comparisons we can say:

- It is ***far*** *better than*
- It's ***way*** *better than*
- It's ***miles*** *better than*
- It's ***worlds*** *better than*

For instance,

> British restaurant food is far/way/miles/worlds better than it used to be 20 years ago.

In the case of *miles* and *far* we can invert the order and say

> *It is better* ***by far***
>    *It is better* ***by miles***

But the phrase: "It is better by way/worlds" sounds off key.

> *British restaurant food is better by far/miles than it used to be 20 years ago*. YES
>     *British restaurant food is better by way/worlds than it used to be 20 years ago*. NO

In the superlative form, the dissonance no longer occurs with *way*.

> *Of all the ice-creams we've tasted, Italian* ***is by far the best***
>   *Of all the ice-creams we've tasted, Italian* ***is the best by far***
>   *Of all the ice-creams we've tasted, Italian* ***is the best by miles*** <sup>[tfd](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/miles)</sup>
>   *?Of all the ice-creams we've tasted, Italian* ***is by way the best*** (dubious)

But the dissonance continues with "worlds"

> *Of all the ice-creams we've tasted, Italian* ***is by worlds the best*** NO

The expression "by far/miles/the best" is idiomatic, but the phrase [by worlds the best](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&espv=2&q=%22by%20worlds%20the%20best%22&oq=%22by%20worlds%20the%20best%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i22i10i30j0i22i30.88968.26133331.0.26135720.84.57.20.1.2.1.240.8624.0j53j1.54.0....0...1c.1.47.serp..29.55.6713.0.EjzZh25Rd_o) sounds off, and Google agrees, displaying only seven results.

Is it ungrammatical? Is it nonsensical? Can you not measure something in *worlds*? Well... yes you can, because a person can do something *worlds better* than another person. How many worlds? Two, three, an infinite number? It doesn't matter, the term *worlds* is used as a form of measurement as proven when it is used in the comparative sense.

If neither "by way better" nor "by worlds better" is idiomatic, what happens with *way* when we use the superlative form in "by way the best"?

I did a little Google research and came up with these figures:

- **by far the best**
  [215](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by%20far%20the%20best%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&ei=V-euU4asEq6O7QaY-oHQCA&start=270&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=653) results
- **the best by far**
  [323](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20best%20by%20far%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&ei=0ueuU7eHKuGM7QbRkYCYDA&start=293&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=653) results
- **by way the best**
  [143](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by+way+the+best%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&ei=h-WuU8uyNIfX7Abe-YGgDw&start=120&sa=N&filter=0&biw=1366&bih=653) results
- **by miles the best**
  [330](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22by%20miles%20the%20best%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&ei=1eauU8vYGsKw7AbJw4CICQ&start=300&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=653) results
- **the best by miles**
  [275](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20best%20by%20miles%22&num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&ei=JuiuU7bRIYXQ7Abz84DQDg&start=283&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=653)  results
- **the best by worlds** (?)
  [8](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22the%20best%20by%20worlds%22&oq=%22the%20best%20by%20worlds%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i8i30l3.72810.76810.0.78798.11.11.0.0.0.0.174.1790.0j11.11.0....0...1c.1.47.serp..0.11.1779.KPT8Cc9PckE) results
- **by worlds the best**  (?)
  [7](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22by%20worlds%20the%20best%22&oq=%22by%20worlds%20the%20best%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i8i30l3.135870.139880.0.142641.9.8.1.0.0.0.204.1261.0j6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.47.serp..1.8.1269.4aojmSB6Bm0) results

1) Does this type of construction and/or flexibility have a name in linguistics? I.e., *It is miles better* / *it is better by miles*

2) Why is "it is better by way/worlds" incorrect but not "it is better by far/miles"?

---

**EDIT**
Many thanks to @Mitch who pointed out that Google's declared results and the actual instances for "by way the best" were way off by miles—*groan*.

Consequently, I've clicked on the last page for each search and noted down the results. You'll see that on every last page Google kindly reminds its users: *In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the XXX already displayed.

If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.*

<sub>(I don't think I'll ever understand how Google calculates its results...)</sub>

Comment: basically this all boils down to "I know you can't say it but I want to know why". Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the data for 'by way the best' (as opposed to, say, 'way the best' or 'by a long way the best')?

Comment: It's in the question but here is the link ["by way the best"](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&es_sm=122&q=%22by+way+the+best%22&oq=%22by+way+the+best%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i22i30l5.5343.8250.0.10015.2.2.0.0.0.0.188.374.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.48.serp..0.2.371.FhueZXQUOVc)  about 5,290,000 results, don't ask me why the figure isn't identical, it's a Google mystery to me. No results for Google books, another mystery for me.

Comment: 1) I've never heard the phrase "by way the best" before in my life, and I can't wrap my head around how to say it. How do you split it? Where's the emphasis? It doesn't even sound like something a non-native speaker would come up with, just a random collection of 4 words (OK, 'the best' works but that's it. Also, check out a couple more pages of your link, you'll find that the number of google hits drops down to under a hundred. Weird, right? It means look further than the first page of hits on google.

Comment: I think that *worlds* is acting as an adverbial genitive here: i.e. it roughly means *my English is better **in the proportion of the world (a great amount)** than yours*.  Adverbial genitives can't usually take prepositions.  Cp. *I work nights*, but not **I work by nights*; *I sometimes walk*, but not **I by sometimes walk*.

Comment: There is more than one native English speaker in the world. To be worlds better, English speakers would need to colonize another world (and then maybe it would become an idiom, on Mars). Also, *best in the world*.

Comment: The _by_ phrase with a superlative refers to a margin of superiority. If somebody is ahead of everybody by miles, he's the best by miles (assuming "ahead" is `Good`). _Way_ is just an intensifier; it's derived from "a long way", but in this construction you'd hafta actually **say** "by a long way"; _by way_ alone doesn't cut it as a margin reference.

Comment: @TimLymington and John Lawyer are both correct when they point out the actual phrase is "**by a long way the best**", is therefore  *by way the best* an ellipsis, a malapropism, plain laziness and ignorance?

Comment: I don't understand what EDIT refers to above. I don't think I've ever heard *by worlds the best* or *the best by worlds*, and I can't find a single instance of either in Google Books. Admittedly, if I search Google *Internet* I find 7 instances of [*the best by worlds*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kIJmWYOfKoP38AfMlb-oBQ#q=%22the+best+by+worlds%22), but 5 of them are for this very ELU post. And the *only* instance of *by worlds the best* is this page. It's just not an idiomatically valid English usage, either way round.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, I think there is a semantic difference between *worlds*, on one hand, and *miles, far* and perhaps even *way*, on the other.

When expressing a comparative or superlative using *miles* and *far*, you are conveying a linear relationship along a single continuum (although I realize you could add a reference to many factors that contribute to that measure). Using @John Lawler's analysis of *way*, being derived from *a long way*, the approach is the same.

*Worlds* however, seems to be a categorical rather than a linear comparison. It is a plural, not a possessive, and seems to indicate that there are numerous spheres of experience that are significantly and qualitatively different. The referenced superior one is on a different plane from the competition. The reference to the First, Second and Third World in geopolitical and technical spheres (or *New World* and *Old World*) has a similar connotation of vastly differing characteristics, often accompanied by an implied preference (or disdain).

While one can contrast the relative *betterness* of two worlds, the *bestness* is more elusive since the existence of numerous non-linear spheres conveys at least potentially infinite numbers of possibilities, and, at least theoretically, there may be other *worlds* yet to be compared, that may exceed the present example.

And surely each of us goes through this cosmological analysis as we mentally compose our excited utterance acknowledging that your question is *worlds better* than my most recent one, and maybe is the best this year *by far*, but it is not the best *by worlds* (although it may be the *world's best* [but that means something else altogether]).

Comment: You left out the "I" in your opening sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, but you are welcome to edit my stuff anytime. It can only help.